# Google Form sending a blank duplicate

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, google-forms

So im using the following code for sendFormByEmail and it works great for sending the required information by email. The only problem is its sending a blank email with all the fields left blank except for the timestamp at the same time. Ive checked for multiple triggers and have removed the trigger and added another one. same thing

the code is

```
{    
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,26).getValues()[0];    
  var email = "jlewis@xxxxxxx.ca"; 
  var subject = "Service Call";
    var message = "";
for(var i in headers) {
    if (e.namedValues[headers[i]]) {
      message += headers[i] + ' : '+ e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + "\n\n"; 

    }
  }
   MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message); 

}
```

Comment: How is this function triggered? And how does it get the `e` parameter? Knowing that may help fix the bug.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58782686/7215091

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending emails twice with MailApp.sendEmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58781729/sending-emails-twice-with-mailapp-sendemail)